# Bitwise OR in %define macros

Tags: rpmbuild

While editing a spec file I came across the following line:

```
%define _udevdir %(pkg-config --variable udev_dir udev | %{_prefix}/lib/udev)
```

I'm not familiar with the rpmbuild syntax, but I assume its author meant that `_udevdir` should contain the value returned by `pkg-config --variable udev_dir udev` command, or `%{_prefix}/lib/udev` if the previous command will return an empty value. But I also assume that this line contains an error.

Can anyone point out if I'm right or not, and if this line does contain an error, how to rewrite it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works correctly:

```
%define _udevdir %(pkg-config --variable udev_dir udev || echo %{_prefix}/lib/udev)
```